# Display: table-cell issue in Firefox

Tags: html, css

I have a div with an H1 and a paragraph inside it. The challenge is to center the paragraph vertically.

```
<div id="id1">
<h1>Header</h1>
<p>paragraph</p>
</div>
```

I use:

```
#id1
{
position: relative;
width: 250px;
height: 250px;
border-radius: 125px;
background: #000;
color: #f00;
}
#id1 h1
{
position: relative;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
top: -50px;
}
#id1 p
{
position: relative;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
top: -37px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
height: 250px;
width: 250px;
border-radius: 125px;
background: #fff;
color: #000;
}
```

It works in most new browsers (even IE8), but not in FF. 
I guess the problem is due to relative position of H1 and P. But not sure.
Help me, please!

The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G3av6/2/)

Comment: could you add a small sketch-image of how it should look like? I don't really see in which vertical space you want to center the paragraph. just the text inside the paragraph inside itself? this works in my FF...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make the `h1` absolutely positioned and then remove the relative positioning from the `p` then it seems to work ok.  Give the `h1` 100% width too to make the text centered again.

```
#id1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 125px;
  background: #000;
  color: #f00;
}
#id1 h1 {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: -50px;
  width: 100%;
}
#id1 p {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  top: -37px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 125px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G3av6/6/

Answer (score 2):

Your h1 tag contains text and FF adds the text height to the header. Try to remove the text, see [here][http://jsfiddle.net/G3av6/3/]